# SQL query to insert IDs in tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will try to be short and concise, I have this table which contains rows of data.

[image]

I also have 3 separate tables, Surgery, TypeOfSurgery and Procedure, each filled with additional data, and each should contain the Id (foreign key) to the previous table.

**For example TypeOfSurgery has a FK column SurgeryId, Procedure has FK column TypeOfSurgeryId etc, I need to update the existing entries in these tables!**

And I also have 3 dropdowns, each connected to the previous one.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**
If I choose Abdominal Surgery the following dropdown should be populated with Appendectomy and Caesarian Section, further if I choose Appendectomy the next dropdown should be populated with procedure A, and if I choose Caesarian section the next dropdown should contain procedure B and Procedure C etc...

My question is how do I give the corresponding IDs to each row in each table with one query, so the dropdowns will work as I described above.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your expected output ?

Comment: SQL Server does not have dropdowns. That's a user interface component. Please indicate what you are using to build the user interface.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid don't worry about the UI, I am simply asking how to insert the appropriate IDs in the respective tables? :)

Comment: So you're asking how to decompose that denormalised dataset into three linked tables. Is this a one-off activity or will data be arriving in this format at a later date and need to be added again?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to decompose this denormalised data into three different tables.

This is how I would do it.

(I wouldn't normally answer a question where the post doesn't contain DDL)

First ensure that all three target tables have an `identity` field defined against the PK so that keys are autogenerated.

Populate `Surgery`. `SurgeryID` in this table must be `IDENTITY`

```
INSERT INTO Surgery (SurgeryName)
SELECT DISTINCT Surgery FROM YourTable
```

Populate `TypeOfSurgery`. `TypeOfSurgeryId` must be `IDENTITY`

```
INSERT INTO TypeOfSurgery (SurgeryID, TypeOfSurgeryName)
SELECT DISTINCT S.SurgeryID, SRC.TypeOfSurgery 
FROM YourTable SRC
INNER JOIN Surgery S
ON S.SurgeryName = SRC.Surgery
```

Populate `Procedure`. `ProcedureId` must be `IDENTITY`

```
INSERT INTO Procedure (TypeOfSurgeryId, ProcedureName)
SELECT DISTINCT S.TypeOfSurgeryId, SRC.Procedure
FROM YourTable SRC
INNER JOIN TypeOfSurgery S
ON S.TypeOfSurgeryName = SRC.TypeOfSurgery
```